# Barcode4J pdf417 module is giving error

Tags: java, barcode, barcode4j

I am trying to convert binary data to pdf417 barcode using pdf417bean class of barcode4J. But it is giving me following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-encodable character detected: Í (Unicode: 205)
    org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.pdf417.PDF417HighLevelEncoder.determineConsecutiveBinaryCount(PDF417HighLevelEncoder.java:468)
    org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.pdf417.PDF417HighLevelEncoder.encodeHighLevel(PDF417HighLevelEncoder.java:108)
    org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.pdf417.PDF417LogicImpl.generateBarcodeLogic(PDF417LogicImpl.java:193)
    org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.pdf417.PDF417Bean.generateBarcode(PDF417Bean.java:79)
    com.pb.iop.labelgen.impl.BarcodeService.generateBarcodecodePDF417(BarcodeService.java:244)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:165)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:276)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1171)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1103)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1053)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1043)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:406)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:477)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Here's a part of codebase I am using

```
        PDF417Bean bean = new PDF417Bean();

        bean.doQuietZone(true);
        bean.setModuleWidth(UnitConv.in2mm(moduleWidthInches));
        bean.setQuietZone(UnitConv.in2mm(quietZoneInches));
        bean.setBarHeight(height);

        boolean antiAlias = false;
        int orientation = 0;

        BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(
                dpi, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, antiAlias, orientation);

        indiciaData = indiciaData.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        byte[] binaryData = Base64.decodeBase64(indiciaData.getBytes());
        String base64DecodedMsg = StringUtils.newStringIso8859_1(binaryData);

        bean.generateBarcode(canvas, base64DecodedMsg);
        canvas.finish();


        String mime = MimeTypes.MIME_BMP;
        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        final BitmapEncoder encoder = BitmapEncoderRegistry.getInstance(mime);
        encoder.encode(canvas.getBufferedImage(), out, mime, dpi);
```

I am using apache commons for conversion from base 64

Comment: The inputData indiciaData is a base64 encoded binary data. Here's a similar bug from Barcode4J bug base http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1903872&group_id=96670&atid=615504. Not sure if This is a similar scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried changing Barcode4J PDF417HighLevelEncoder class and changed encoding to ISO-8859-1 in place of Cp437. I generated a handful of barcodes and they are getting scanned correctly. Looks like it can be changed to support ISO 8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use new String(binaryData, "Cp437") instead of ISO-8859-1. The [page on PDF417](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/symbol-pdf417.html) says to use that encoding. Other encodings are not currently possible. Unfortunately, the "Í" is not in Cp437 so can't be used. If you download Barcode4J from CVS HEAD and compile it yourself, you can use RFC 2397 data URLs to use binary data: [PDF417 description for development version](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/trunk/symbol-pdf417.html).

Comment: I tried with data url too unfortunately I got the same error even then. Is there any other stable open source library I can use for pdf417 generation?

Answer (score 0):

Jeremias pointed out the solution, just for the simplicity use:

```
new String("your string goes here written in UTF-8".getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp437")
```

for example:

```
new String("ČĆŽŠĐ čćžšđ or Í".getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp437")
```

you can check out barcode decoding online: http://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/default.aspx

It works fine for Croatian diacritic characters, and it sohoud work for any UTF-8 character. Srdačno.